# Why is my Add to Cart button appearing next to the image instead of below the image even on using the line break tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an eCommerce site. I have a header and a sidebar. And then I have the main body section. In the main body section, I have a heading for Featured Products. And then I have some images below the Featured Products heading which I will replace with actual images. But when I add the image, and then I also add the Add the Add to Cart button below each image. But when I add a button, it is coming right to the image instead of below it. Even though  I have a line break tag.
Some help will be really appreciated

Thanks

The index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Partials/header.php';
 ?>
 <br><br><br><br>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Style.css">

<div class="main_wrapper">
<?php
    require_once 'Partials/sidebar.php';
?>


  <!--The main body section start here-->
<div class="main">
    <!--Featured Products List Starts Here-->

    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Featured Products</h2>
  <div class="container">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <br><button>Add to cart</button>
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <br><button>Add to cart</button>
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <br><button>Add to cart</button>
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <br><button>Add to cart</button>
    </div>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">New Arrivals</h2>
    <div class="container 2">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
    </div>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Clothes</h2>
    <div class="container 3">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
    </div>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Brands</h2>
    <div class="container 4">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
      <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
    </div>

  <style>
      .container {
        display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      overflow: auto;
      justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .container > img {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }

    </style>


  <!--Featured Products List Ends Here-->
  <button name="Black">Black</button>
</div>
<!--The main body section ends here-->

<!--Back To Top Coding Starts Here-->
<head>
<style>

    #back-to-top-btn{
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        border: 3px solid #333;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        transition-property: background-color, color;
    }

    #back-to-top-btn:hover, #back-to-top-btn:focus{
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
    }

    /* Animations */
.btnEntrance {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: btnEntrance;
}
/* zoomIn */
/* @keyframes btnEntrance {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
} */

/* fadeInUp */
@keyframes btnEntrance {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.btnExit {
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: btnExit;
}
/* zoomOut */
/* @keyframes btnExit {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }
} */

/* fadeOutDown */
@keyframes btnExit {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
}

</style>
</head>
  <button id="back-to-top-btn"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-up"></i></button>

<script src="js/Back_To_Top.js"></script>
<!--Back To Top Coding Ends Here-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And then this is the header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home - Diamond Collections</title>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1cde82a3ba.js"></script>
        <style>



            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600');

:root {
  --background: rgba(0, 214, 170, .85);
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    /*background-image: radial-gradient(circle, red, yellow, green);*/
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.content {

}

/* navigation styles start here */

header {
  background: var(--background);
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
}

/* changed this from the tutorial video to
   allow it to gain focus, making it tabbable */
.nav-toggle {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: -9999px !important;
  left: -9999px !important;
}

.nav-toggle:focus ~ .nav-toggle-label {
  outline: 3px solid rgba(lightblue, .75);
}

.nav-toggle-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-toggle-label span,
.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  height: 2px;
  width: 2em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before {
  bottom: 7px;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  top: 7px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--background);
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
  transform: scale(1,1);
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav a {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav-toggle-label {
    display: none;
  }

  header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;
    height: 76px
  }

  .logo {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    position: absolute;

    height: 200px;
    //transform: scale(2,2);

  }

  nav {
    // all: unset; /* this causes issues with Edge, since it's unsupported */

    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    transition: none;
    transform: scale(1,1);
    background: none;
    top: initial;
    left: initial;
    /* end Edge support stuff */

    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: flex;
  }

  nav li {
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  nav a {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
  }

  nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.75em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;
  }

  nav a:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}






h1 {
     margin:0
}

.logo a {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
}

.logo img {
    height: 74px;
    margin-top: 1.1px;
}




        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
  <h1 class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="Images/Logo5.JPG"></a></h1>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
      <form action="" method="" class="search" style="margin-top: 24px;">
      <input type="" name="search" placeholder="Search..." style="padding: 5px; font-size: 15px">
      </form>
  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
    <span></span>
  </label>

</header>
```

And then this is the sidebar.php

```
<style>

    .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  margin-top: 6.1%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

</style>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">New Arrivals</a>
  <a href="#">Featured</a>
  <a href="#">Clothes</a>
  <a href="#">Brands</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your code and the reason you're not getting the result you want is because you put everything inside the div CONTAINER.

You put IMG BUTTON IMG BUTTON IMG BUTTON IMMG BUTTON so when the code runs it displays everything in a straight line as it actually is.

in order to get the result you want you need to structure your code with more divs inside the container div.

EXAMPLE:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="test">
        <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
        <button>Add to cart</button>
     </div>
     <div class="test">
        <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
        <button>Add to cart</button>
     </div>
     <div class="test">
        <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
        <button>Add to cart</button>
     </div>
     <div class="test">
        <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
        <button>Add to cart</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need more help.
And P.S keep your style code inside the style.css and not html files.

Comment: Yes, it worked. But If I place another button below the image, and add text-align right. Even then the button appears on the bottom left of the image. I want 1 button to appear on the bottom left and the other button to appear on the bottom right.

Comment: @Soban A quick solution for adding 2 buttons would be to put the buttons in another div and in the css make the display of that div display: inline-flex;

 <div class="container">
      <div class="test">
        <img src="Images/Logo5.JPG">
        <div class="buttonst">
          <button class="addtocard_btn">Buy</button>
          <button class="addtocard_btn">Add to card</button>
        </div>
      </div>

css:

.buttons{
    display: inline-flex;
}

I doubt it's the best example but it does the job.